# How to detect a long pressure on an AnnotationView on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to reproduce the effect of the iOS dashboard on my map annotation by wobbling them once I long press one of them. Yet I am stuck at detecting when a user has long pressed one. Here is code:

```
override init(annotation:MKAnnotation, reuseIdentifier identifier:String) {
    bookingImageView = UIImageView(image: self.bookingImage)
    ...
    let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleLongPressure:"))
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;  //user must press for 2 seconds
    bookingImageView.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
}

func handleLongPressure(notification: NSNotification){
    wobble()
}
```

It does not work, either if I associate the gesture to the annotation or to its `subview(bookingImageView)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was wiring to the drag operation that in some way presupposes a long touch.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set user Interaction enabled

```
bookingImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: No way, I think the long pressure event is caught by the annotation to know when to start dragging.
The handleLongPressure function is never called anyway.

Comment: How did you do it? I sort of fixed the thing by attaching to the dragging operation that is some way presupposes a long touch.